# Eclipse (Android) overwrites id

Tags: android, eclipse

I have one layout with a button. Id of button is "loginEmailButton".
Then I make copy/paste this button in another layout and trying to change id to "loginFacebookButton". After that id of first button do changed too.

Why?

Comment: Maroun this is crazy wrong, how would a copy-paste do that?
@OP: you probably just used `Alt+Shift+R` to rename, this will rename all occurences. Just use plain text edit or clean-build your project as Szymon suggested and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite the field by typing . changing id in the properties will change the previous ids. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the integer in R.id?

Try to clean your project and build again. Eclipse has problems with resource identifiers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just close your eclipse and open it again its done :)

Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

After you copy paste it, completely delete the id field, then rewrite it by hand:

1. Type id, hit ctrl+space
2. Select the "@+id\" field
3. Type your new id normally

Hope this helps.